# MSDOS API serial port only reading last sent character

Tags: serial-port, dos

I've been playing with the MSDOS API in assembler for some time and I'm trying to build an application to read/write from the serial port. I'm currently using VMware Workstation 11 + VSPE (http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) to emulate the serial port communication.

One thing I noticed is that if I send let's say "asdfgh" into the serial port and then read it in MSDOS (Using interrupt 21h function 03h, but I also tried interrupt 14h function 02h), it only returns the last character read: "h"

According to some documentation I read, if an application sends data faster than I can process it, characters will be lost, which means that either there is another way to make MSDOS save bytes to a buffer (controlling flow) or I have to write a driver that does this (or maybe a TSR program that manages this I dunno).

So the question is, do I have to write a driver or is there another way to do this?

Comment: There's no point in writing a driver. Just access the device (a 8250/16550) UART) directly. Alternatively slow down the baud rate and poll as fast as you can so not bytes get lost.

Comment: Problem is that data transfer is user initiated, so slowing down the baud rate would help, but if one of the users takes too long to type the command the data is lost anyways

Comment: No, bytes would be less likely to get lost if the user types slower. You do however need to be polling **before** the user starts typing. After it's already too late no matter what the baud rate or typing speed. For something simple like copying characters to the screen, this will work fine. You can easily do that faster than anyone can type. For more complex things like file transfer you'll need to access the hardware directly since the MS-DOS (and the BIOS) serial APIs don't provide the necessary functionality.

Comment: With typing it works fine just now, but with files it's an issue. So I guess I'll have to write something to access the hardware directly (as you pointed out in my other question), so I guess either a TSR that reads from serial port and stores it into a buffer (which I can empty through a software interrupt) or a driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write a program that turns on the 16550 FIFO buffer and now It works using the DOS API.

So it was just the FIFO buffer

No need to slow down the baud rate or whatsoever. Nonetheless, if one happen to have a 8250 it's probably either that or implement a communications driver on top of it

Also, this helped a lot:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/8250_UART_Programming#UART_Registers